# CiviCRM System Status: You are missing a rule of type Supervised for: Individual

Tags: system-status, dedupe-rules

I have the following in the system status warning, can someone please help to explain and solve this, Thanks a lot.

For CiviCRM to function correctly you must have at least 2 dedupe rules configured for each contact type. You are missing a rule of type Supervised for: Individual
Configure dedupe rules

Answer (score 1):

Go to contacts > find and merge duplicate contacts. In the individual rules section add or set one rule to a supervised rule.

A supervised rule is one that casts a wide net when scanning for duplicate contacts in the backend when adding a new contact or scanning for duplicates. It's supervised therefore should only be used intentionally by an admin user reviewing a potential duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

See the user guide for an explanation: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/#dedupe-rules

But briefly, under "Contacts - Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts" you are missing some rules.